# Is it posible to POST request the responseType "array buffer"?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, axios

I made an api that will return an image. at first I tried it on get method request and it works, but for security reasons I need to make it to post method but post is not working like my get method. Do you think that responseType is available only in get method since it is not working on my post method?

Here is my code using get method that works:

frontend:

```js
export const getImageFile = async (imageName) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/image/${imageName}`,{
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
      });
      const image = new Buffer.from(data, "binary").toString("base64");
      return `data:image/png;base64, ${image}`;
    } catch (err) {
      alert("File not found.");
    }
  };
```

backend (php symfony):

```php
/**
     * @Route("/api/graph/image/{imageName}", methods={"GET"}, name="get- image-graph")
     */
    public function getImage($imageName)
    {
        try {
            $file = $this->parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir').'/public/graphImage/graphs/'.$imageName;
            $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);
            return $response;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->json(['error' => 'File not found'], JsonResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

here is my code when I use POST method that doesnt works:

frontend:

````js
export const getImageFile = async (imageName) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/image`,{
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        "imageName": imageName,
      });
      const image = new Buffer.from(data, "binary").toString("base64");
      return `data:image/png;base64, ${image}`;
    } catch (err) {
      alert("File not found.");
    }
  };`

backend: 

```php    
    /**
     * @Route("/api/graph/image", methods={"POST"}, name="get-image- 
     graph")
     */
    public function getImage(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            $imageName = $content["imageName"];
            $file = $this->parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir') 
            .'/public/graphImage/graphs/'.$imageName;
            $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);
            return $response;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->json(['error' => 'File not found'], 
            JsonResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }`
````

Comment: For post method use `$image = $_POST["imageName"]` Because you are not sending it as json

Comment: I send it as json based on my frontend request. I get the image based on devtool (success request) but it is not appearing on my frontend. I think my responseType is not working when I tried it on post.

Comment: `headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }`   is not present in your post request. So try $image = $_POST["imageName"]

Comment: I tried but it cause an error.

Comment: try my answer and let me know

Comment: @IndraKumarS ok bro, I will try it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api),

```
axios.post(url, data, config)
```

Your post request:

```
const { data } = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/image`,{
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        "imageName": imageName,
      });
```

It seems you mixed data and config. So your post request should be

```
const {data} = await axios.post(
    `${apiUrl}/image`,
    {
        "imageName": imageName,
    },
    {
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
    }
);



// In server side php,you access it like
$image = $_POST["imageName"];
```

And if you would like to send it as json, use headers in config

```
    {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }
```

Comment: Hi Indra, I just mixed the data and configuration, after I separated it, It works like a magic. I appreciate your help Thank you so much :) I learned so much from you as a beginner.